# Vagrant: Interface Down Following Build

Tags: vagrant, yaml, vagrantfile

Following "vagrant up", the private network interface (enp0s8) isn't started automatically. If I access the machine via "vagrant ssh" and manually run "ifup enp0s8" it starts without issue.

My Vagrantfile is as follows -

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define "centossean" do |centos7|
    config.ssh.insert_key = false
    centos7.vm.box = "geerlingguy/centos7"
    centos7.vm.hostname = "centossean"
    centos7.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.157.10"

    centos7.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.memory = 4096
      vb.cpus = 2
    end

    config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
      #ansible.verbose = "v"
      ansible.inventory_path ="inventory"
      ansible.limit = "centossean"
      ansible.playbook = "playbooks/main.yml"
    end
```

Has anyone come across this before? I did have a look online, but I'm fairly new to Vagrant so it's likely to be something straight forward...

I'm using the following versions -

- Vagrant 1.9.1
- VirtualBox 5.1.10 r112026
- Guest OS - CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511

Generated ifcfg-enp0s8 contents are as follows -

```
[vagrant@centossean ~]$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s8
#VAGRANT-BEGIN
# The contents below are automatically generated by Vagrant. Do not modify.
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.157.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
DEVICE=enp0s8
PEERDNS=no
#VAGRANT-END
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Answer found -

```
config.vm.define "centossean" do |centos7|
    centos7.ssh.insert_key = false
    centos7.vm.box = "centos/7"
    centos7.vm.hostname = "centossean"
    centos7.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.157.10"
    *centos7.vm.provision "shell", inline: "nmcli connection reload; systemctl restart network.service"*
```